# Why I am getting different build variant options after adding CMake option

Tags: android, android-studio, cmake

When I try to change my build variant option from debug to release, I found varies options like debug-x86, debug-arm64 v8a, release-x86, release-arm64 v8a,etc..
The above changes appears only after adding CMake options. I don't know how to choose the buildConig before running the app.

[image: Confused to choose the buildconfig]

Comment: On Stack Overflow we prefer **text** over *images* whenever possible. Since a code can be expressed as a text almost in any case, the code should be included into the question post as **text**. See [ask].

Comment: The second image appears to be unrelated to your question. Did you intend to provide some different image information here? Also, please provide **textual** descriptions of this issue when possible. Links to images such as these can become stale and render your question much less useful.

Comment: In the 2nd image I notified my .cpp file, this file has a method Java_com_example_securedsharedpreference_MainActivity_getAPIKey(), how can I call this getAPIKey() method from Activity2 class??   @squareskittles

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but it is not clear to me how the second image is *related* to your original question about choosing a build configuration..

Comment: @squareskittles Sorry for the confusion. I'm newly trying this CMake concept to make my keys secured. Both the images pointing 2 different questions. I try to run my app by changing the buildConfig in relesae mode, there I see different congig options as mentioned above(1st image) .

Comment: @Pavithra Ok, to avoid confusion, you could post a separate question about this other topic. On Stack Overflow, questions should be focused to a *single* topic (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions)) to make your problem more clear to those who can help.